# how i can avoid this :The username is not different from the current username

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, telethon

Hi how can I avoid reusing the same user?

I can't find a solution to this. I have a list of 3 usernames but after he changes once he is unable to change to another one again.. Does anyone have a solution for this?

```
username_list = ['zRRrrwx2231221s', 'bzRRrrwx2231as', 'azRRrrwx2231s']


random_username = random.choice(username_list)
print('A randomly selected username is:', random_username)

with TelegramClient(StringSession(ses_string), api_id, api_hash) as client:
    while True:
        try:
            time.sleep(10)
            
            result = client(functions.channels.UpdateUsernameRequest(
               channel= 'zRRrrwx2231221s' ,
               username = random_username
            ))
```

> telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.UsernameNotModifiedError: The username is not different from the current username (caused by UpdateUsernameRequest)

I just want it to switch between the three users regularly - I don't care if one of them catches I'll switch.. but it can't run thanks to the helpers

Comment: You could just check it yourself, and skip the call if it won't do anything. You can catch that exception and pass. On a separate note, add some debug prints because I don't think that loop is doing what you think it's doing.

Comment: I'm not good at programming.. I'm learning and it's a hobby, so I'm asking for help here for this moment its doiing it.. but after one time after its changed its can not change anymore..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments, it's always trying to pick the same username. But the error you're getting appears to be if you "change" the username, but it's the same as before.

https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/account/update_username.html

If that's the case, you have two options.

1: remember the username and just skip the change, so you don't get the error. This has the added benefit of not attempting an api call that you know will fail.

```
import time
import random

username_list = ['zRRrrwx2231221s', 'bzRRrrwx2231as', 'azRRrrwx2231s']
previous_username = None
while True:
    try:
        random_username = random.choice(username_list)
        if random_username == previous_username:
            print('we decided to stick with the same username (do nothing)')
        else:
            print('changing username to', random_username)
            #result = client(functions.channels.UpdateUsernameRequest(
               #channel= 'zRRrrwx2231221s' ,
               #username = random_username
            #))

        previous_username = random_username
        time.sleep(10)
    except Exception as e:
        print(type(e), str(e))
```

2: just do it anyway, catch the exception, and then ignore it. Easier to ask forgiveness than permission programming. So add a handler for UsernameNotModifiedError.

```
while True:
    random_username = random.choice(username_list)
    try:
        result = client(functions.channels.UpdateUsernameRequest(
           channel= 'zRRrrwx2231221s' ,
           username = random_username
        ))
    except UsernameNotModifiedError:
        pass
    time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: Did I misunderstand the question, and you just wanted to know how to pick a random but different username each time? With this code, you avoid/handle the error, but you still randomly might stay on the same username sometimes. Perhaps you want random.shuffle?

Comment: yes. the freinds here already help and i so glad for it now i try to serch online how i can pick up the  channel automaticly xD ty so much

Comment: yes its work perfectly exept wen its get on the same user he lost the 'channel' and cannot keep change..

Comment: i wanna say big ty and all of the answers! ty so much!!!!!! all work perfectly thnkss alooot

Comment: "Easier to ask forgiveness than permission" is usually fine, but here we're dealing with API calls to an external service (Telegram) which will likely incur flood limits when a call is made, whether it succeeded or not.

Answer (score 0):

This `random_username = random.choice(username_list)` happens only once when you call it and is a variable. To make it possible to call it again you need a function like:

```
def rnd_username():
    random_username = random.choice(username_list)
    print('A randomly selected username is:', random_username)
    return random_username
```

Now instead of `username = random_username` you need to call `username = rnd_username()`

Comment: yes its now back to the list :] but now its send me this after 1 times "telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.UsernameNotModifiedError: The username is not different from the current username (caused by UpdateUsernameRequest)"